# performance question

Tags: mesh, objects

I have build a huge tower of blocks and floors with the array modifier about 20.000 blocks.However i need to separate them.When i separate them from loose parts the pc does ages and i think that it will never stop separating (i let it all night open, and nothink happened).
Is there an other way that will make me able to separate my cubes?

Please help i want to finish my physics simulation D:

Comment: Does the blocks and floors have any modifiers?

Comment: no they dont (they had but i applyed them)

Comment: did they have a Sub Surf Modifier?

Comment: no they dont.The only modifiers they used to have was 3 arrays that have been applyed before i tryed to seperate the blocks

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your system? If you can't subdivide the cubes, chances are you'll have issues with the physics simulation as well. Can you post an image of your model?

Comment: i have 8 gb ram but swap memory is about 60 gb so ram may not be the problem :/ also when i had task manager on , blender didn't used more that 2 gb ram